# Converting a string to a char array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, char

Let's say I have a string like this.

```
Dim str As String = "code"
```

I need to break this string down to an array of characters like this,

```
{"c", "o", "d", "e"}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every string is an implicit char-array. So you can get the 3rd char by:

```
Dim char3 = str(2)
```

**Edit**: Just for the sake of completeness. You can also use [`String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) to convert the string instance to a new `char-array` instance. The core benefit of using `ToCharArray` is that the char-array you receive is mutable, meaning you can actually change each individual character.

Note that you could also use `LINQ`. If you for example want the first three characters of a String:

```
Dim firstThree As Char() = str.Take(3).ToArray()
```

Comment: That's all I wanted to know. :D I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

```
dim chars as Char() = str.ToCharArray()
```

Comment: Tried this now and it works too. :) Always good to know extra ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim str As String = "code"
' Use For Each loop on string.
For Each element As Char In str 
Console.WriteLine(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing @AlexeiLevenkov,

> You can use
>   [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx)
>   to convert it to array of characters, or use
>   [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=VS.95).aspx)
>   if you like LINQ more:
>
> ```
> Dim delimStr As String = " ,.:"
> Dim delimiter As Char() = delimStr.ToCharArray()
>
> "foo".ToArray()
> ```

<sub>(I added the above alternative as the duplicate question will be soon closed; it is worth keeping the [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) alternative.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I did some benchmarking and ToCharArray is approximately 30 times faster than LINQ's ToArray.