# Is there a shorter way of creating a string array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

Currently I am using this to create a string array

```
New String() {" ", ".", ";"}
```

Is there another way that does not require so many characters, say without the New String() part perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835959/converting-a-string-to-a-char-array

make a string and explode it in to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can usually infer the type of the array from its elements, e.g.

```
Dim stringArray = {" ", ".", ";"}
```

Note - this doesn't work when the array is empty, because there are no elements to examine.

```
Dim stringArray = New String() {} ' specify the source type, infer the destination type
Dim stringArray As String() = {}  ' specify the destination type, infer the source type
```

Comment: I had been passing in character arrays as an argument to a filter function like Filter(SomeString, New String(){".", ","})

Wish I would have just tried Filter(SomeString, {".", ","})

Comment: If you want an empty array `Dim stringArray As New String()` would be shorter without Infer being on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim stringArray = " . ".Cast(Of String)().ToArray()
```

Comment: Cool ... throws an exception (invalid cast from char to string) here (VB2012)

Comment: `Dim s = "ABC".Select(Function(c) c.ToString).ToArray`. This one works, but you only save characters (in source) for longer arrays of course.