# Is there a function to convert a String into an array of Char

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a string to a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835959/converting-a-string-to-a-char-array)

I'm coding the following

```
Sub Main()
    For index As Integer = 0 To "foo".Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine("foo".Chars(index))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit")
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Is there a `property` in the `String` `class` that will return an array of `Char`?
So as an alternative to the above I could do something like:

```
Sub Main()
    For each c as Char in ConvertToCharArray("foo")
        Console.WriteLine(c.ToString())
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit")
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

---

ref
Very similar [**SO Question HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835959/converting-a-string-to-a-char-array)

Comment: Can't you use .ToArray() ? :P

Comment: thanks Ken - agreed it looks like a definite duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is a [`IEnumerable(Of Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) already:

```
For each c as Char in "foo"
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: +1 for trumping the other answers! (and for the references)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .[ToCharArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) method to achieve what you want.

Comment: +1 cheers for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) to convert it to array of characters, or use [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) if you like LINQ more:

```
Dim delimStr As String = " ,.:" 
Dim delimiter As Char() = delimStr.ToCharArray()

"foo".ToArray()
```

Comment: literally, 27 seconds behind me xD

Comment: +1 thanks for extra `LINQ` alternative; just a case of me impoorting the `LINQ` namespace and that shared method will be available? Oi - @GamErix - it's not a race (...or is it?)

Comment: no it's just funny how fast the answer are coming :p

Comment: funny and frustrating at times ...you ever try posting answeres to SQL logic questions ; three or four answers within a couple of minutes!